# $NP\subseteq TIME[O(n^{\log n})]$

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, complexity-classes, np

Is it more plausible that $NP\subseteq TIME[O(n^{\log n})]$ than $NP\subseteq P$? I don't see this mentioned much and is there a reason why? If this question doesn't make sense, explain why.

Comment: Notice that, for every $c$, $n^{\log n} > n^c$ eventually. (Actually, this happens exactly when $\log n > c$.) $n^{\log n}$ grows faster than any polynomial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is definitely more plausible, for the simple reason that $NP \subseteq TIME[O(n^{\log n})]$ is implied by $NP \subseteq P$. However, it is conjectured that $NP$ requires exponential time (this is known as the *Exponential Time Hypothesis*), and so both statements are conjectured to be false.